# ASP.NET MVC 5 - RazorGenerator vs Publish Precompile during publishing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently using VS.NET 2015 with ASP.NET MVC 5
I would like to have my razor views precompiled,

I'm a little confused about which is the best way to have my views precompiled:

1. RazorGenerator (what advantages does this have?)
2. VS.NET Publish Wizard "Precompile during publishing", does the "allow precompiled site to be updated " need to be ticked off? Does this actually precompile razor views?
3. `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`

How do I know if my views a precompiled?

Comment: if the views have any compile error, precompiling will show it,  if not compiled, it will only show up when the views are called, and views that are not compiled will take a bit time to load the first time, I dont know technically

Comment: thanks Arun I guess that's one way of checking if a view is precompiled, I'm just wondering which of the above methods is the way to go?

Comment: precompiling can be chosen from, right click on the view and select compile, this is better, from performance point doesn't batter, server is powerful, wont notice.. for debugging i turn it on

Comment: Can anyone answer this please? What's the actual difference between RazorGenerator and VS Publish Wizard precompile? Why would you choose one over another?

Answer (score 0):

- RazorGenerator precompiles during Design time (the generation happens as soon as you save the file). So, you'll know errors before build and your views will be compiled before publish. It can be used to share views between projects putting them in a specific assembly too.
  The disadvantage of this solution is that you'll have more "wait time" than combining the others options
- "Precompile during publishing" precompiles views at publish time to avoid a compilation on first web access but only if you tick off "allow precompiled site to be updated"
- `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` can be used to find out if there is a problem with views at build time. Your views won't be compile on publish with this option. You can see it like a debug tool.

Comment: Can you clarify the "wait time"? The purpose is to have a faster load when accessing the page, your answer suggests it's slower?

Comment: @Diana "Wait time" is about time to compile because compilation occurs on each "Save" with this first solution.